# How to apply transform to graphics in OpenFL

Tags: graphics, transformation, haxe, openfl

I'm converting a JavaScript library to Haxe. In this library, there is an animated effect constructed with many of shapes. So I used the [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/) library to render shapes.

But now I have a technical problem with transformation.
Some of the shapes has the child shapes so it's transform should be applied to the child shapes too.
For example, please imagine shapeC is attached on shapeB and, shapeB and shapeD are also attached on shapeA. In this case, shapeB, shapeD should be transformed by both of transformA and their own transform and, shapeC also should by transformA, transformB and transformC.

To achieve this, is it a good solution to render the same level shapes in one graphic and apply the parent's transform to that graphic? (on above example, render shapeB and shapeD to one graphic and a apply transformA to that graphic)

I think it's not a good **optimized solution** to calculate the final transform from all parents transforms and apply that to all vertexes of that shape. Please tech me the best optimized solution for rendering.
Any suggestion will be welcome.

And if there is any confused things on this question, please pardon me and let me check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Sprite` class:

```js
var parentShape = new Sprite ();
parentShape.graphics.beginFill (0xFF0000);
parentShape.graphics.drawRect (0, 0, 100, 100);

var childShape = new Sprite ();
childShape.graphics.beginFill (0x00FF00);
childShape.graphics.drawCircle (0, 0, 50);
childShape.x = 200;
childShape.y = 200;

parentShape.addChild (childShape);
addChild (parentShape);
```

Each shape will use its own canvas element, so if you create a lot of shapes, you may decide to flatten it into a single image when you are ready. This is possible using `cacheAsBitmap` or `bitmapData.draw`

```js
parentShape.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

...or

```
removeChild (parentShape);

var bitmapData = new BitmapData (Math.ceil (parentShape.width), Math.ceil (parentShape.height), true, 0);
bitmapData.draw (parentShape);
var bitmap = new Bitmap (bitmapData);
addChild (bitmap);
```

Comment: Hi, Joshua. thanks for your answer. But I want to apply full transform, not only the position. On the other hands move position, scaling and rotate with Matrix. Also I'm not sure it is efficient to use so many _Sprites_ for only animated effect. That will be used to show some effect for only one sprite like as fireworks explosion, opening gift box, animated logo and so on. Sorry to make a confusion, but would you edit the answer for me again? Regards

Comment: You can either use the `childShape.rotation` property (in addition to `scaleX`/`scaleY`) or you can use `childShape.transform.matrix = new Matrix ();` using whichever transform you need. Another option (for performance) would be to use `bitmapData.draw`, then a `Tilemap`

Comment: Hi, Joshua. I have successfully implemented the transforms with Sprite class. so all shapes are set on correct position. But now I still have GPU memory leak problem, even though tried both of your suggestions (cache and bitmapdata). Because this is the animation, all shapes will be redrawn in each frames (one frame in 0.03 second). So totally it increases GPU memory to over 200MB, and animation looks stuck. But in the original JS library it's only less than 15MB with the same sample. so I'm sure there is an exact way to optimize GPU memory usage. Do you have any suggestions? Regards

Comment: OpenFL currently draws shapes in software. On HTML5, that is canvas. Each `sprite.graphics` will have it's own canvas element, if it is drawable. Is it possible to combine your shapes into one graphics object? This will still not use WebGL for the shapes, but the rest of your project (at least) can be accelerated

Comment: I think, the main reason of GPU memory leak is generating so many sprites in short time. I will try to draw child shapes on parent's graphics directly. In this case, the main problem for applying transform on graphics will occur again, but I think that's the best solution.